# How to reset a form by (this) selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

In the function below, reseting form doesn't work!

```
$('#myform').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) 
  {
    $(this)[0].reset(); // error : $(...)[0].reset is not a function
  }
}
```

How to resolve
Thank you

Comment: Just use $(this), not $(this)[0]

Comment: `$(this)` creates a jQuery object with a stack size of one, containing the element `this`.  `[0]` breaks out the first element of the jQuery object stack as a raw dom element.  Given that, do you see why it doesn't make sense that you are doing those two things back to back?

Comment: same error @David Partyka

Comment: Also reset is a raw dom method, not a jQuery method.  So what you are doing in the `...` is possibly important.  Provided that the `this` is the form element you should be able to do just `this.reset()`.  If that does not work, then you need to verify that the `this` is the form.

Comment: Try using: this.reset();

Comment: Sorry I don't undestand, How to make it work @Taplar?

Comment: I just told you how.  Try `this.reset()` and if you get an error, debug your logic and verify that the `this` is the form.  You can do that in any number of ways, one being to console log it.  Another being to throw in a `debugger;` statement in there and look at it in your browser debugger.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/r9sy0zx6/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.reset is not a function @Taplar

Comment: So now start debugging.

Comment: @AmineDahou Please [edit] your question and include any other relevant details there (Not as a comment)

Comment: Ok @Alon Eitan it's done

Comment: @AmineDahou You can add `var form = this;` right after `event.preventDefault();`, and then inside the `$.post` callback you need to use the reference of the form `form.reset()` (Instead of `$(this)[0].reset();`)

Comment: It's working thank you @Alon Eitan , $(form)[0].reset(); also work now

Comment: @AmineDahou That's good to know :) BUT - Don't use `$(form)[0].reset();` because you're just wrapping the element with jQuery and then unwrapping it, bad practice performances-wise and unnecessary

Comment: Ok @AlonEitan, How to mark question as answered?

Comment: @AmineDahou You can post your answer and accept it (You can self-answer and accept your own answers), or accept the current answer posted by NightOwlPrgmr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$('#myform').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) 
  {
    // post callback function - $(this) is no longer 'myForm'
  }
  $(this).trigger('reset'); // trigger form reset after $.post()
}
```

What you would want to ensure is the form was successfully posted prior to the form reset, so maybe in the $.post() callback you could set a variable and then check that before triggering the reset.

Something like this:

```
var can_reset = false;
$('#myform').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) 
  {
    // unsure if your response returns data.success - just an example
    if (data.success == true) {
        can_reset = true;
    }
  }

  if (can_reset) {
      $(this).trigger('reset');
  }
}
```

Comment: This _might_ work (Not sure about `trigger('reset')` though), but there's also the possibility that the ajax post request will fail and you might want to NOT reset the form in that case

Comment: 100% working, you are genious @AlonEitan :), Thank you

Comment: @AlonEitan Yep, already thought of that.. thanks! `trigger('reset')` works the same as the HTML reset button, so should be supported fairly well

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr The second solution will probably won't work because `$.post()` is asynchronous, but as long as the first suggestion works then it's good enough for me :) +1